# How does one compare different instances of the same Swift enum?

Tags: ios, swift, types, enums

Take this enum and the three literal instances of it that follow:

```
enum Types {
    case string(String), int(Int), bool(Bool)
}

let t1 = Types.string("one")
let t2 = Types.string("two")
let t3 = Types.int(3)
```

How can these be compared so that `t1` and `t2` match (as the same enum case, even though their values differ), whilst `t1` and `t3` do not match (as they are different cases of the same enum), like this?:

```
func compare (lhs: Types, rhs: Types) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}

print(compare(lhs: t1, rhs: t2)) // prints "true"
print(compare(lhs: t1, rhs: t3)) // prints "false"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by conforming `Types` to `Equatable` protocol:

```
extension Types: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Types, rhs: Types) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.string, .string), (.int, .int), (.bool, .bool):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

print(t1 == t2) // true
print(t1 == t3) // false
```

---

UPD.

You should think about formatting your code. [Swift api design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) said:

> Follow case conventions. Names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.

So, there is no uppercase `case`s should appear in your code.

Spaces between parentheses should be trimmed as well.

---

UPD 1.

> if I want to get the value "one" out of let t1 = Types.String( "one" ), is that possible and if so how?

Sure. The `if case let ...` can help you here:

```
if case let .string(value) = t1 {
    print(value) // "one"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @pacification. I had to Uppercase the first char of the (.type, .type) pairs to match the enum, but otherwise this works perfectly. Nice!

Comment: Question @pacification : if I want to get the value `"one"` out of `let t1 = Types.String( "one" )`, is that possible and if so how?

Comment: Hi, @JosephBeuys'Mum. I updated my answer and re-formatting you main question again (see `UPD` why).

Comment: thanks @pacification. I'm absolutely with you on the camel casing, just overlooked that this once. As for the gaps in parentheses, I've never understood this. I mean, imagineifallthewordsinasentencewerewithoutspaces. Would that be readable? No. It's not readable in plain English, and it's equally unreadable in space-less code. So why the recommendation to ram every character up against every other character into onelongstreamofunreadablecharacters?